# How constructors / destructors are used when creating / adding objects to a container

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to learn how the constructors / destruction are used when creating and adding objects to a container. For the XClass in the example below, a simple constructor, a copy constructor, a move constructor, and a destructor are implemented:

```
std::vector<XClass> v;
    v.push_back(XClass(1));
    v.push_back(XClass(2));
```

I used console to track how the constructors and destructors are called, below is what I got. The message "with argument x" refers to the argument passed in when constructing the object. When it's 1 it refers to the first object XClass(1), and similarly for XCLass(2). The destructor is called with 0 because the object had been initialized by the move constructor.

```
1.simple constructor called with argument 1.
2.move constructor called with argument 1.
3.destructor called with argument 0.
4.simple constructor called with argument 2.
5.move constructor called with argument 2.
6.copy constructor called with argument 1.
7.destructor called with argument 1.
8.destructor called with argument 0.
```

I can understand all the lines except 6 and 7. the first object is created and added through line 1 to 3. The second object is created and added with line 4, 5, and 8. Why do we need to copy object and destruct it again at line 6 and 7, especially considering we are adding the second object to the back without moving the first one?

Comment: What does the "with X" portion of your output signify?  Is it the value you passed to the XClass constructor?

Comment: it is the argument passed in when creating the object. I will clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid push XClass into std container. you should push std::unique_ptr<XClass> instead.

Comment: Why is your copy constructor not called on first push? It seems to me that the class was simply memory managed by the class vector...

Comment: Is your move constructor declared `noexcept`?  (Try it both with and without.)

Comment: @SunggukLim thanks for the advice. I will keep it in mind when working on actual project.

Comment: @Fabien my understanding is that the move constructor in the XClass was called to move the temporary object just created to the vector.

Comment: @aschepler no I did not declare it as noexcept. I will see if I can add it to make the constructor more robust.

Comment: @DavidY If you make it `noexpect` then when reallocation happens the old elements will be tranfered to the new inner buffer via move constructor instead of copy constructor; if the move constructor is more efficient than copy constructor then the whole reallocation will be less expensive.

Comment: @SunggukLim The problem with using unique_ptr (or shared_ptr or similar) is that if you go that route, you are required to allocate every XClass object from the heap, which adds a non-negligible amount of overhead in terms of RAM and CPU usage compared to just using a regular vector<XClass>.  It also means that the XClass objects won't be stored contiguously in memory, which can reduce the efficiency of the CPUs' memory caches, slowing the program down.  Finally, unique_ptr makes it difficult to make a copy of the vector<XClass>.  Smart pointers are worthwhile only with "big" objects.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Or with polymorphic objects, when you want to put different derived types in the same container.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I wanted to mention that too but I hit the comment length limit :)

Comment: @songyuanyao I just tried to set the move constructor noexcept, and it now triggers the move constructor rather than the copy constructor. Is it always a good practice to set move constructor noexcept?

Comment: @SunggukLim thanks for the tip. There is probably not a clear line, but roughly how big an object should be to warrant a smart pointer?

Comment: @DavidY Yes, and not only for move constructor, it's always good practice to declare functions `noexcept` if they won't throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> especially considering we are adding the second object to the back without moving the first one?

The 1st element is moved in another style here.

For [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), when the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` the reallocation happens to extend the storage capacity.

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and
>   contracted as needed. Vectors usually occupy more space than static
>   arrays, because more memory is allocated to handle future growth. This
>   way a vector does not need to reallocate each time an element is
>   inserted, but only when the additional memory is exhausted. The total
>   amount of allocated memory can be queried using `capacity()` function.

When it happens [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will allocate the new inner buffer, and copy all the existing elements into the new buffer, then destroy them and deallocate the old inner buffer. That's why you see one copy construction and destruction.

You can reserve the storage capacity via [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid reallocation, e.g.

```
std::vector<XClass> v;
v.reserve(2);
v.push_back(XClass(1));
v.push_back(XClass(2));
```

Then you won't see additional copy construction and destruction.

Comment: Does that mean I should define a proper size first to avoid triggering the reallocation, which seems quite expensive?

Comment: @DavidY Yes!! I added it to my answer. To be precisely it's proper *capacity*.